# Handle and register protocol in electronjs

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to open an Eelectron app from the browser via URI ("openfoobar://paratmers")

I did register the protocol via `registerHttpProtocol` and add the registry entry.
When I click on the link `<a href="openfoobar://para1">Open in Notes</a>`
the application opens but no parameters are received.

Please review the code below.

**package.json**

```
"protocols": [{
    "name": "openfoobar",
    "role": "Viewer",
    "schemes": ["openfoobar"]
}]
```

**main.js**

```
const PROTOCOL_PREFIX = "openfoobar"
protocol.registerStandardSchemes([PROTOCOL_PREFIX])

...

protocol.registerHttpProtocol(PROTOCOL_PREFIX, (req, cb) => {
    console.log('passed params ' + req);
    //mainWindow.loadURL(fullUrl)`
})
```

I expect to see in the console `passed params para1`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out on macOS you need to handle open-url event instead:

```
    app.on("open-url", (event, url) => {
        console.log(url);
    });
```